# How to properly use async function from onPress

Tags: flutter

I am trying to do some image processing using filters, and image package. I can make it work, but it hangs the UI.

```
class ImageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static MaterialPageRoute route(String path) => MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => ImageScreen(
            imagePath: path,
          ));

  final String imagePath;

  const ImageScreen({Key key, this.imagePath}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ImageScreenState createState() => _ImageScreenState();
}

class _ImageScreenState extends State<ImageScreen> {
  int value = 0;
  Filter _filter;
  final _random = Random();
  _ImageScreenState();
  Widget _animatedWidget = const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

  Future<Widget> _createImage(Filter filter) async {
    value++;
    _filter = filter;
    var bytes = await File(widget.imagePath).readAsBytes();
    var i = await  image.decodeImage( bytes );
    _filter.apply(i.getBytes(), i.width, i.height);
     return Image(key: ValueKey<int>(_random.nextInt(200)) , image: MemoryImage(image.encodeJpg(i)));
  }
  void _initiate(Filter filter) {
    debugPrint("initializing");
    _createImage(filter).then(
        (widget)=> setState(()=> _animatedWidget =widget));
    debugPrint("done");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initiate(NoFilter());
  }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(body:
      Stack(
        children: [
          AnimatedSwitcher(child: _animatedWidget, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),),
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                color: Color.fromRGBO(200, 200, 200, 0.9),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('Original'),
                      onPressed: () async  {
                       _initiate(NoFilter());
                      },
                    ),
                   
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('B&W'),
                      onPressed: ()  {
                          _initiate(MoonFilter());
                      },
                    ),
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('Dusty'),
                      onPressed: ()  {
                          _initiate(ReyesFilter());
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
          )
        ],
      ));
    }
  }
```

What I want to happen is that the processing to be off main thread, and then see a nice transition. Unfortunately something is blocking the main thread.
The button gets stuck in depressed state, and then, after the process finished,  page flickers and shows the new image.

Answer (score 2):

you have to make this function to `async`

```
 Future<void> _initiate(Filter filter)async {
    debugPrint("initializing");
    _createImage(filter).then(
        (widget)=> setState(()=> _animatedWidget =widget));
    debugPrint("done");
  }
```

and if you want to call this function then you can call like

```
 onPressed: () async  {
     await _initiate(NoFilter());
       },
```

Comment: this didn't make any difference